# css clear an element and make the other one follow

Tags: html, css

I am making this basic thing were there is a label followed by a textblock and on another line there is a button with a textblock for the answer besides the button.

I want the button(generateButton) and the textblock for answer (answerField) under the label (labelDay)and the first textblock(dayInput) but when I clear left on the button and the answerbox it sets the button under the label and first inputbox but my answerbox goes under my button and it needs to be besides it. Is there a way to do it without a br tag?

This is my code so far

```css
#labelDay{
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#dayInput{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#generateButton {
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}

#answerField{
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}
```

```html
<label for="dayInput" id="labelDay">Geef een dag in:</label>
<input type="text" id="dayInput"/>

<input type="button" id="generateButton" value="Genereer tekst" class="answer"/>
<input type="text" id="answerField" class="answer">
```

Comment: I already found it i needed to do only a float left on aswerfield and not a clear left but can anybody explain me why?

Comment: clearing left means you clear the left float of any preceding items - so by putting it on the answerfield, you negate the float of the generateButton, pushing the answerfield onto a new line - read this: https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: But is it because i put float left on generateButton and answerField that answerField sort of follows generateButton?

Comment: You need to learn about floating and when to use it - as one of the answers have pointed out, inline elements will appear on the same line next to each other anyway so why you use floats in your situation is strange.  Also css has moved on a lot and the need for floating items is a lot less common.  There will always be a better way to position them left and right (as there are a lot of bugs and browser issues that come with floating items)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it - you just need to remove the `clear: left` from `#answerField`.

Floats make elements "flow" around eachother - you can imagine a bunch of `float: left` elements as each trying to move as far to the left as they can without touching another element or going off the side of the screen before going to the next line.

A clear on an element forces itself, and any floated element after it to the next line - so your clear on `#generatButton` is already starting a second line, and the on `#answerField` is starting an unwanted 3rd one.

```css
#labelDay{
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#dayInput{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#generateButton {
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}

#answerField{
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<label for="dayInput" id="labelDay">Geef een dag in:</label>
<input type="text" id="dayInput"/>

<input type="button" id="generateButton" value="Genereer tekst" class="answer"/>
<input type="text" id="answerField" class="answer">
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use float in this situation?
All Elements are inline-elements. So they would appear next to each other.

My approach is to define two div-blocks for the rows (no css):

```html
<div>
  <label for="dayInput" id="labelDay">Geef een dag in:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dayInput"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="generateButton" value="Genereer tekst" class="answer"/>
  <input type="text" id="answerField" class="answer">
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt knew about that at school they tell us to not use a lot of div elements but thanks for sharing that i will remember this :)